# Why is this a valid approach to coding within the Java Main Class

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have recently see some Java code that I have simplified below. I don't understand why someone would want to use new Main() within the Main Class. Could someone explain the circumstances why this would be used?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // write your code here
         new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
         System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: To get out of the `static` context, of course.

Comment: To demonstrate constructors?

Comment: `public Main() {
         System.out.println("hello world");
    }` is just a constructor.

Comment: assuming that your code isnt all only static stuff, you will have to create and object at some point and call some methods on it

Answer (score -1):

It's valid in the sense that it compiles and runs, but it's not really conceptually correct.

You are creating a new object of type `Main` only to immediately discard it again. Its constructor is being used not as a true constructor (because its not initializing anything, and the stateless object will be thrown away anyway) but rather as just another method.

So that being the case, why not **use** another method?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         doStuff();
    }

    public static void doStuff() {
         System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Is `doStuff` really adding anything here? Not particularly. It gives us the opportunity to give a meaningful identifier to the method, where previously we were forced to use the name `main`. Maybe that's valuable, maybe its not.

Comment: That was my thinking too. Why create a new object Main, and invoke the constructor,  when the code could just be placed in the original main method.

Comment: @P.Hill Yeah. Not sure how its possible to disagree with this. A constructor constructs things. Its there in the name. If it doesn't construct something useful, don't use it.